# WP_Query order by which meta_query clause is passed?

Tags: wordpress

When using a meta query with multiple clauses using a relation of "OR", how can I order the results by which clause passed? For instance, I'd like to return the "Completed' statuses last, and there are other statuses not shown.

```
$args = [
   ...
   'meta_query' => [
      'relation' => 'OR',
      'clause_one' => [
         'key' => 'status',
         'compare' => 'IN',
         'value' => ['Registered', 'Pretested']
      ],
      'clause_two' => [
         'key' => 'status',
         'value' => 'Completed',
      ]
   ],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this :-

```
$args = [
   ...
   'meta_query' => [
      'relation' => 'OR',
      'clause_one' => [
         'key' => 'status',
         'compare' => 'IN',
         'value' => ['Registered', 'Pretested']
      ],
      'clause_two' => [
         'key' => 'status',
         'value' => 'Completed',
      ]
   ],
  
'orderby' => [
        'clause_one' => 'DESC',
        'clause_two' => 'ASC',
    ]
]
```